# Tag suggestion: Protocol

Tags: discussion, tags, interesting-tags, tagging

Questions involving the underlying protocol do not seem to have a relevant tag. If I wanted to ask

> What encryption protocol(s) does Tor use

or

> How does Tor choose relay and exit nodes

I guess both could fit under anonymity but what question on this site wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a rep level you have to hit before you can create tags (you may have to have at least a few points). Feel free to tag questions with [protocol](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protocol).

Comment: I've never been sure how one creates a tag on SE

Comment: Just add it to the question like you normally would; it will be created automatically. Then you can go in and edit the tag wiki if you so desire.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that [protocol](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protocol) is a good tag.

Currently (in beta stage) you must have at least 150 reputation to be able to create tags. In the private beta stage the requirement was probably much lower (probably 1).

As Sam wrote to add a tag just type it to the **Tags** field followed by a space. You can freely edit tag wiki after earning trusted user (4000 reputation). Now you can suggest tag wiki edits which will be approved by users with 1500 reputation or moderators.

See [privileges](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and [site-moderators](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators).

Answer (score -1):

**Everybody with reputation higher than 150 can now create new tag ! You have not to make a topic on meta about it !** Just add it to a "Tags" input in a new question mode - it will be created automatically. You can read more [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) and [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/tagging).