# tag deletion: protocol

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently I stumbled across the tag [protocol](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protocol). It has currently 14 tagged questions of all sorts of topics. The tag was created after a [discussion here](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26/88).

I wanted to create a tag wiki, but when browsing through all questions I was quite unsure what this tag is all about. It should Tor-related protocols, like Tor spec, rendezvous spec etc., but also other protocols, like encryption protocols, network protocols etc. I think this tag is too broad, because basically it covers all sorts of questions. From my opinion it provides no real value and I'd propose to delete it. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the tag is fine; it's a good place to put questions about protocols used by Tor. Instead of moderating tags (unless they're blatant spam), we should focus on moderating questions and answers that use them.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2):

As this site is still in its relative infancy we're bound to need some fairly broad tags. If we try to get too specific we could end with a one-to-one question/tag relationship, which would be incredibly counter-productive.

Once the site is better established and has enough content we can start having monthly tag cleanups like out [sister sites do](//meta.superuser.com/q/5718/203529). For now, if any new questions get tagged with **protocol** when they shouldn't be then users can certainly flag/edit them as we go.